# entry point in setup.py

Tags: python, pip, package, entry-point

```
/project  
../project/script.py  
../project/__init__.py  (This is a blank File)
setup.py  
other files like README.

#script.py
def function1():
    print "hi"

def main():
    function1()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


#setup.py
setup(
name='project',
version= __version__,
long_description=markdown_contents,
packages=['project'],
entry_points={
  'console_scripts': [ 'project=project:main']
  }
)
```

I am able to to pip install and stuff. but when I run project once the package is installed ,
I get *init*_.pyc'> has no 'main' attribute
I just want to run the functions in main of script.py when I run project command on the box.  What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 10):

Your main project package indeed doesn't have a `main` attribute. `project:main` means: import `main` from the `project` module, and you don't have such an object in `__init__.py`.

You probably want to refer to `project.script:function1` instead. That object *does* exist.

Best practice is to define a `main()` function, and use that as an entry point:

```
def function1():
    print "hi"

def main():
    function1()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Now you can add more to `main()` as needed.

Note that the `__name__ == '__main__'` test will always be *false* when the `script` module is imported by the script generated by setuptools. The file is not run directly.

Comment: What if I have a sequence of functions under if __name__ == '__main__':, and I want to execute them all in the order ? THanks for the reply.

Comment: @script_kiddie: the `__main__` test is *not* an object. Define a separate function `main()` and call that.

Comment: still gives __init__.pyc'> has no 'main' attribute
. Check the corrected code.

Comment: Check the entry point; it should be `project.script:function1`, *not* `project:function1`.

Comment: super important! you might want to restart / start a new console to see the 'entry_point' work,   i spend a while with out restarting the cmd that i was working on, and i couldn't figure it out, till i restarted the computer for a windows update and all start working. lol hope my pain help others.

Answer (score 2):

```
'console_scripts': [ 'project=project.module:main']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `pyproject.toml` file to configure entry point

```
[project.scripts]
hello-world = "project.script:main"
```